# How do i put the serial number in each table row while using {{#each}} loop in handlebars?

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js, express-handlebars, hbs

I am creating a table to show list of items from the database, but how do I put the serial No. for the list when using an {{#each}} loop:

```
 <table class="table mt-5">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">No.</th>
                <th scope="col">Title</th>
                <th scope="col">Category</th>
                <th scope="col">Description</th>
                <th>Image</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {{#each products}}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row">1</th>
                <td>{{this.Name}}</td>
                <td>{{this.Category}}</td>
                <td>{{this.Description}}</td>
                <td><img  style="width:100px" src="/product-images/{{this._id}}.png" alt="Img"></td>
            </tr>
            {{/each}}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This is the table I am using. In the `<th>` tag I have written `1`. I want to replace it with the sl. no. This is an .hbs file and I am using Node.js and MongoDB as database.

How can I do it?

Comment: What is an "sl. no."?

Comment: serial number ! or we can say the index number starting from 1.

Comment: I don't understand, is the serial number a property belonging to each product, or is it just a count of each row? - `1, 2, 3, ...`

Comment: Yes, the count of each row

Answer (score 0):

Handlebars provides a [data-variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#index), `@index`, for getting the index of current item in an `#each` iteration. However, like JavaScript arrays, `@index` is [0-based](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering), so your result would be `0, 1, 2, ...` - which is not what you asked for. To use `@index`, the impacted line in your template would become:

```
<th scope="row">{{@index}}</th>
```

If you require your serial numbers to start a `1` it will require a little more work. There is nothing out-of-the-box from Handlebars that will allow us to add `1` to `@index`. We would need to write a [custom helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers), a very simple one. For example:

```
helpers: {
  increment(num) {
    return num + 1;
  }
}
```

And then our template would become:

```
<th scope="row">{{increment @index}}</th>
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/d5nqkzw6/) is an example fiddle for reference.

My feeling about this approach is that it is excessive to add a helper for such a simple purpose. I would recommend adding a `SerialNumber` property to each Product *before* it is passed to the template, before the `res.render()` call. It would look something like:

```
products.forEach((product, index) => {
  products[index].SerialNumber = index + 1;
});
```

This way, the `SerialNumber` will be available to each Product in your template:

```
<th scope="row">{{this.SerialNumber}}</th>
```